# Sponsorship Undertaking SU07

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for normal family visit visa for my mother and brother to visit me in UK from Pakistan. I am myself British citizen. 
Their visa was rejected based on ECO's remarks about not being satisfied with my brother's financial situation.

I want to apply for their Visa again, but this time I want to use Sponsorship Undertaking SU07 form which means that I will be legally responsible for the travel arrangements. My question is can I send them Sponsorship Declaration form SU07 even though it is general family visit visa .I am not calling them on dependent Visa.

My second question is if I use this Declaration form, will they still have to  prove that they have means to support their travel even though when I am submitting the declaration form.

Comment: Although it doesn’t fully answer your question, there is a section on sponsorship undertakings in this answer https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e